Azure Powershell: Get-MgUser not recognized
I ran Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Applications and Connect-MgGraph with many scopes. I am now trying to run the command New-MgUser, but I receive this error:
Get-MgUser: The term 'Get-MgUser' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
Does anyone have suggestions on how to fix this so I can run New-MgUser and Get-MgUser?

You are missing the module that has those 2 cmdlets:
Install-Module Microsoft.Graph.Users

Also, Connect-MgGraph is from Microsoft.Graph.Authentication not from Microsoft.Graph.Applications.
You can always use Find-Command to verify that:
PS ..\pwsh> Find-Command Get-MgUser, Connect-MgGraph

Name               Version    ModuleName                        Repository
----               -------    ----------                        ----------
Get-MgUser         2.25.0     Microsoft.Graph.Users             PSGallery 
Connect-MgGraph    2.25.0     Microsoft.Graph.Authentication    PSGallery

